# How do i test create lead user case in Jmeter for muliple users

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

When user there is a new user (Identified through new Mobile No) then system store details and create an Unique ID for Customer,

But how to do performance testing for this scenario for 1000 Virtual Users, Only getting 1 Successful and others unsuccessful due to It required different Mobile No for each user

#### Request

```json
{
  "firstName": "Ankit",
  "lastName": "Singh",
  "mobileNumber": "8169089997",
  "vehicleData": [
    {
      "registrationNumber": "UP32MX0505",
      "vehicleType": "CAR"
    },
    {
      "registrationNumber": "KA01HP8748",
      "vehicleType": "BIKE"
    }
  ],
  "otherVehicles": [
    {
      "vehicleRegistrationNumber": "UP43Z0064",
      "make": "Volvo",
      "model": "Xc90",
      "fuelType": "Hybrid (Electric + Petrol)",
      "vehicleType": "CAR"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Response

```json
{
  "id": 331,
  "mobileNo": "8169089997",
  "firstName": "Ankit",
  "lastName": "Singh",
  "emailAddress": null,
  "avatarId": null,
  "profileImageUrl": null,
  "gender": null,
  "city": null,
  "failedToSaveVehicles": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using different mobile numbers for different users? For example you can consider using [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and [__longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) functions combination like replacing your `8169089997` with `${__longSum(8169000000,${__threadNum},)}`

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: Thank you for your help can you please share me the Request Screen shot